# Create a table from the output of a Snowflake Stored Procedure that uses Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've written a Stored Procedure that pivots a table (as a workaround for the lack of dynamic pivot tables in Snowflake).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pivot_table(tableName VARCHAR, index VARCHAR, columns VARCHAR, vals VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE()
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'pivot_the_table'
AS
$$
def pivot_the_table(session, table_name, index, columns, vals):
    df = session.table(table_name).to_pandas()
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
    SEP = ","
    index = index.split(SEP) if SEP in index else index
    columns = columns.split(SEP) if SEP in columns else columns
    vals = vals.split(SEP) if SEP in vals else vals
    pvt = df.pivot_table(index=index, values=vals, columns=columns, aggfunc="sum").reset_index()
    return session.create_dataframe(pvt)
$$;
```

It works fine, but I can't figure out how to save the output as an actual Snowflake table. Or is there maybe even a way to achieve this with a Snowflake function?

In a perfect world, I would be able to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE some_table AS
SELECT
   *
FROM (
    pivot_table(table, "month", "year", "sales")
) AS pvt
LEFT JOIN some_other_table AS oth ON pvt.month = oth.month;
```

I'm aware that Stored Procedures can also use SQL as language, but I'd rather use Python if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out. This will save the table to the active Database and Schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pivot_table(tableName VARCHAR, index VARCHAR, columns VARCHAR, vals VARCHAR, output_table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'pivot_the_table'
AS
$$
def pivot_the_table(session, table_name, index, columns, vals, output_table_name):
    df = session.table(table_name).to_pandas()
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
    SEP = ","
    index = index.split(SEP) if SEP in index else index
    columns = columns.split(SEP) if SEP in columns else columns
    vals = vals.split(SEP) if SEP in vals else vals
    pvt = df.pivot_table(index=index, values=vals, columns=columns, aggfunc="sum").reset_index()
    session.create_dataframe(pvt).write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table(output_table_name.upper(), table_type="")
$$;
```